# Spark streaming maintain state over window

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

For spark streaming, are there ways that we can maintain state only for the current window? I understand `updateStateByKey` works but that maintains the state forever unless we purge it. Is it possible to store and reset the state per window?

To give more context. I'm trying to convert one type of object into another within a windowed stream. However, the conversion is the following:

Object 1 is either an invocation or a response.

Object 2 is not considered complete until we see both a invocation and a response.

However, since the response for the an object could be in a separate batch I need to maintain states across batches.

But I only wish to maintain the state for the current window. Are there any ways that I could achieve this through spark.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mapWithState transformation instead of updateStateByKey  and you can set time out to the State spec  with duration of your batch interval.by this you can have the state for only last batch every time.but it will work if you invocation and response depends only on the last batch.other wise when you try to update key which got removed it will throw exception.
MapwithState is fast in performance compared to updateStateByKey.

you can find the sample code snippet below.

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
val stateSpec =
  StateSpec
    .function(updateUserEvents _)
    .timeout(Minutes(5))
```

Comment: Is there a way to maintain this for a window duration? I am hoping to use this for a sliding window. From what you are describing with the expiration it doesn't look like you can deal with sliding windows?

Comment: As an additional follow up.  Can we return a windowed version of the mapwithstate stream which would be composed of only one RDD?

Comment: So In this if you set the time out to you window time it always will have the data for one window